# What tag should be used for "first-timer" questions?

Tags: discussion

I found a few questions erroneously tagged with [ubuntu-one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu-one) where OP seems to have intended to express "I am new"...
e.g.

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/849817/novice-computer-user-how-will-it-effect-how-i-use-my-computer
- [Startup error Uncleared pch fifo underrun on pch transcoder](https://askubuntu.com/questions/840496/startup-error-uncleared-pch-fifo-underrun-on-pch-transcoder)
- [I had updated ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04 but thats not working can anyone help me?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/832578/i-had-updated-ubuntu-14-04-to-16-04-but-thats-not-working-can-anyone-help-me)
- [Ubuntu 14.04 hangs on purple screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/832321/ubuntu-14-04-hangs-on-purple-screen)
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/826983/ubuntu-16-04-wifi-not-listing

In some cases the wrong tag can be removed but for some posts it is the only tag given - what should we use to convey that "first-timer" feeling?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Nothing. That is a characteristic of the OP, not of the question. Tags describe the question itself, they help match experts to the subjects they are experts in and can answer questions about. Nobody's an expert in newbies.

Having a tag whose sole purpose is to indicate that the poster of a question is new to Linux would not in any way make those questions easier to find and/or answer. I can't think of any beneficial effect such a tag might have and can think of a few detrimental ones.

If you find a mistagged question, just edit and tag more appropriately. The OP might have thought a "newbie" (which is what they assumed ubuntu-one meant) tag might be relevant but you don't need to add it just because they did. Just tag the question with whatever tags describe it best.

Comment: Of course you are right.  One explanation for my asking this question: I was surprised to see that many new questions tagged with [tag:ubuntu-one].  So to get into real mode: What would you do with the first Q in my list? (That's the one that triggered the whole thing).

Comment: @guntbert that first one isn't even a good fit for AU.

Comment: @guntbert I'd close it, like RolandiXor did :) in general, o would just retain with a relevant tag. But not one indicating that the OP is new to Ubuntu